# Gitlab Runner is active but not doing jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have gitlab-runner installed on my machine (mac os), registered a runner as sudo, Settings->CICD->Runners shows the runner is active. However, the runner is not working any jobs. Jobs are queued up and stuck on "pending" status. Also note, upon registration Settings->CICD->Runners showed the runner but was inactive. I had to run `gitlab-runner verify` for the runner's status to show active.

Using the sample yml:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - sleep 60
    - echo "Code coverage is 90%"

lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "No lint issues found."

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

My registration parameters:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor "shell" \
  --url "https://gitlab.myorg.org/" \
  --registration-token "MY_TOKEN" \
  --description "runner-test" \
  --maintenance-note "Free-form maintainer notes about this runner" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --locked="false" \
  --access-level="not_protected"
```

What are some recommended steps to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: A couple of us were discussing GitLab runners in the [Git chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55870620#55870620) just now. Perhaps we can chat there if you're interested!

Comment: Question posts are for questions and not answers. See [ask] and [answer]. Please move the solution you found to an answer post.

Answer (score 1):

**Soultion Found**

Needed to start the gitlab-runner service. Because I installed gitlab-runner via brew, I had to start the service using `sudo brew service start`. And then I could check that status using `sudo gitlab-runner status --service homebrew.mxcl.gitlab-runner`. After this, pipeline works fine.

Comment: When I install via choco, i dis not need to start the runner but if I download the binaries and install it myself then I had to start the runner